# View a ListFragment from a Fragment that's in a FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I have a MainActivity that extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener, I have a tab class that extends Fragment from in this I can call another class called Manual_Add that extends Fragment by calling:

```
Fragment ManualAdd = new Manual_Add();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.addToBackStack("manual").replace(R.id.WebView, ManualAdd).commit();
```

All this works fine.

I have another class that called Search it extends ListFragment implements OnClickListener, I cannot get this page to load from the same class as I can get the ManualAdd to load.

I tried ListFragment SearchT = new Search_T();

I have also tried

```
    Search_Data Search=new Search_Data();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager =getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.WebView, Search);
    transaction.commit();
```

But get a error on transaction.replace(R.id.WebView, Search);

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`getChildFragmentManager()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager%28%29) in your first Fragment.

Comment: Still same error

1 quick fix available: 
change of type 'Search' to 'Fragment'